# Mechanize link with JavaScript href in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to follow a link with href as Javascript in ASPX using Mechanize.

I traced the link using node in mechanize, but could not send click event.

```
slink=page.link_with(:node => page.at('a[@id="lbtnRole_2"]'))
page=slick.click
```

Getting following error:

```
page=slick.click -- in `<top (required)>'#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `slick' for main:Object>
```

When i tried to emulate form submission like in javascript, i get no error. But could not navigate to second page as well.

```
page = agent.get('http://somepage.aspx')
search_results = page.form_with(:name => 'MainForm') do |form|
  form.field_with(:name => "__EVENTTARGET").value=''
  form.field_with(:name => "__EVENTARGUMENT").value='role'
end.submit
```

Web page link and Javascript below

Link:

```
 <a id="role" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('projectrole','a000~AA~XYZ~Y~2~~others')" class="style_ProjectCentral_ProjectRole" href="javascript:__doPostBack('role','')" style="color:DarkBlue;font-family:Arial;">TM</a></td><td></td>
```

Javascript - Does the below:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
  var theform;
  if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
    theform = document.MainForm;
  }
  else {
    theform = document.forms["MainForm"];
  }
  theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
  theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
  theform.submit();
}
```

Mechanize object of the current page:

```
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "TM" "javascript:__doPostBack('role','')">}
```

Can you let me know the way to naviagate to the next page?

Comment: Please learn how to format your question. The text box used for question entry has a number of formatting shortcuts, along with good help that describes how to use each feature. Proper formatting makes it easy to understand your question. Bad formatting, such as what you've given us, makes it difficult to read, which discourages people from taking the time to help you.

Comment: It's a typo - slink/slick, pick a better variable name and it will be easier to spot those.

Comment: Aplogies... reformatted my question to make it clear...